# Properties of the indiscrete rational extension of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $X = \mathbb R$ equipped with the topology generated by open intervals of the form $(a,b)$ and set of the form $(a,b)\cap \mathbb Q.$ Then

1. $X$ is regular.
2. $X$ is normal
3. $X$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $ X$
4. $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $X$

My attempt is :

for (3) $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon) \cap \mathbb Q$ is nbd of a $\in \mathbb Q$ intersect with $X$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is empty, so $X$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is not dense in $X$

for (4) i think $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $X$

Please give  me the counter example of (1) and (4).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution to (3) appears correct to me (a tiny bit more later).

For (4) you just need to show that every nonempty open set contains a rational number.  The nonempty open sets in this space are just unions of the sets you described (*i.e.*, sets of the form $(a,b)$ or $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$  for $a<b$).  So it really suffices to show that all of these sets contain a rational number: this shouldn't be too difficult.

For (1) and (2) I'll just leave a hint.

**Hint:** Note that $F = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is closed in this new space.  (This is essentially what you proved in your solution to (3).) Can you separate $0$ and $F$ by disjoint open sets?  (In a bit more detail, if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$, find an irrational number $x$  such that every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $U$.)

Comment: Fisher : Thanks for your appreciate help,  $F^c$ = $\cup_{a\in \mathbb Q}(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon) \cap \mathbb Q$, so F is closed, if $\exists$ U and V such that $0 \in U \ \ and \ \ F \subseteq  V$ and $U \cap V = \phi$ $\Rightarrow \ \ U \subseteq V^c \subseteq F^c = \mathbb Q$. further what should be done to get a  contradiction .

Comment: @user112064: If $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$, then there must be an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $( - \epsilon , \epsilon ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq U$.  Note that $( - \epsilon , \epsilon ) \cap F \neq \emptyset$.  For $x \in ( - \epsilon , \epsilon ) \cap F$, what do the neighbourhoods of $x$ look like?

Comment: Fisher : Thanks

Comment: @user642796: Sir, is am I correct, neighborhood of $x$ must be open interval like $(x-δ, x+δ)$ because $x$ is irrational number. Then what? Is that mean this neighborhood of $x$ must intersect with $U$, so that $X$ will be not regular!? Further how to show not normal? Please help me I am beginner in topology.